# Como obtener los nombres de las columnas de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, oracle, phpmyadmin

quiero obtener el nombre de las columnas de dos tablas, tengo una consulta que me devuelve los datos de dos tablas relacionadas, pero también quiero obtener el nombre de esas columnas.
He investigado y se como hacer que salga el nombre de las columnas de una tabla pero yo quiero el nombre de las dos tablas.

aquí les muestro como están relacionadas las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la consulta que me devuelve los datos de las dos tablas es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ahí, quiero obtener también los nombres de las columnas, con esta consulta solo obtengo la de una sola columna ¿Cómo seria de la de dos columnas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo, dices "con esta consulta solo obtengo la de una sola columna" Pero en la foto aparecen todas las columnas

Comment: Primero para hacer un comentario lee bien, quiero obtener los nombres de las dos tablas, segundo para hacer un comentario así ni respondas, y tercero falta el de la tabla rol

Comment: En tu WHERE en lugar de usar TABLE_NAME es igual a... utiliza Where TABLE_NAME IN ('usuarios', 'roles').